# return data from nested jquery ajax get request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, get

I have 2 JAVASCRIPT API Get calls I'm making using JQUERY. I want to append HTML I build up within the second call to the DOM.

The first call grabs some data. I cycle through the length of this data making a second call for every index.

Within the the second call I build HTMLContent up.

Once all calls are done, I append HTMLContent to the DOM.

I'm struggling to return HTMContent back to within the first call, as I only want to append the DOM when it is completely built up. AND outside the `for` loop I have created.

I know I could append the done from within the 2nd call but I'd really like to know how to return it.

I was thinking perhaps I need to create a promise but not sure this would help as the scope would still be be contained to the second get request `.done` func

This is what I have so far.

```
var gallery = (function($){

    var init,
        firstGetCall,
        secondGetCall,
        HTMLContent = '';

    init = function(){
        // Make first call
        firstGETCall();
    };

    // Declare firstGETCall func
    firstGETCall = function(){
        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/data.json',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                numberOfItems: 10
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {

            //  Cycle through each data element
            for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
                // Make second call
                secondGetCall(data[i]);
            };
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
        // I want to append the DOM here with the conplete HTMLContent - built up of 10 x <div><img... elements
        // However I'm stuck as to how to return the complete HTMLContent
    };

    // Declare secondGetCall func
    secondGetCall = function(singleData) {

        $.ajax({
            url: 'http://example.com/data-2.json',
            type: 'GET',
            data: {
                type: singleData
            }
        })
        .done(function(data) {

            // Build HTMLContent
            HTMLContent = '<div><img src="' + data.image + ' title="' + data.subTitle + ' alt="Photo"></div>';
            // I do not want to append the DOM here
            // return HTMLContent doesn't work
        })
        .fail(function(error) {
            console.log(error);
        });
    };

    return {
        init: init
    };

})(jQuery);


gallery.init(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 0):

First the most important point:

> I want to append the DOM here...

**Anyway you can't do anything at the place where you put the above comment!**

Since Ajax works asynchroneously (unless you specify the opposite, but it's strongly discouraged), any statement at the place you designate will be executed a few microseconds after the `$.ajax` is launched, so long time before your whole HTML is built.

Now this seems also weird:

> I'm struggling to return HTMContent back to within the first call

First because, again due to async mode, you can't expect *returning* anything from the `.done()` of an Ajax call.
But also because I don't see why you want to "return back" a data that is already available at a higher level. In fact what you need is only to be notified when it is available.

In the other hand I totally agree it's better to append HTML to the DOM only once, to reduce time consumption.

Then for this to work, my first thought is: **why not simply have a unique server function, returning the whole set of needed data, rather than two different ones?**

However, in the case it's really not possible for some reason, you might actually make the Ajax calls to work synchroneous (but again you should avoid it).
In this case you have to :

1. In your `secondGetCall()` function, slightly modify the `.done()` body statement to append new data to `HTMLContent` rather than merely setting it: `HTMLContent += '<div>...</div>'`;.
2. In each of the two Ajax calls, add `async: false` to the Ajax object.
3. Write the statement to append HTMLContent to the DOM at the place you wrote the comment about that.

Comment: Thanks @cFreed - so it sounds like I want to keep it async. How would I modify what I have to achieve that? Again, struggling to understand where and how I can put a notification in to say when everything it complete and the HTMLContent is built up.

Comment: and in your answer at Point 1. Unless I'm mistaken I am appending (concatenating) the new data by using the `+=` assignment

Comment: @fidev First answering your last comment: yes, what I'm suggesting is to successively populate `HTMLContent` by appending each new part, then (point 3) use the actual whole HTML text to append to the DOM. What puzzles you here?

Comment: @fidev Regarding your previous comment: more difficult to have a _good_ answer. If you want to keep it async, the only other way I can think to is something like: 1) add a `.complete()` handler to `secondGetCall()`, where you increase a counter (previously defined at the function top); 2) add a `.complete()` handler to `firstGETCall()`, where you append HTML to the DOM _when the counter == your desired numberOfItems_. But you must realize that __this is merely another way of working synchroneously__! So again I suggest you consider working once for all at the server level.